# Android: how to 'insert' a layout into another layout?

Tags: java, android, xml

I wasn't quite sure on how to ask this, but it would essentially be the equivalent of a custom directive in HTML, pseudo code below:

**Main layout**

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <TextView text="Our song list"/>
    <LinearLayout>
        <CustomLayoutHere>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Custom layout**

```
<LinearLayout orientation="horizontal>
    <TextView text="Song name:"/>
    <ImageView background="albumart.png"/>
    <Button text="Add to favorites"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

So essentially this custom layout piece would be added into the LinearLayout above, once for each song.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `include` tag:

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <TextView text="Our song list"/>
    <LinearLayout>
        <include layout="@layout/custom_layout"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Fair enough, however when using custom directives in html, with the help of angular, you can use ng-repeat.

How can I do a 'repeat' on <include> so that it includes one instance of that layout for each object I'm iterating through?

Comment: There is no tag to do 'repeat' on xml. You will have to do it programmatically with a for loop and inflating the view.

Comment: Typically you wouldn't use an include for this either-  you'd use a listview or gridview and use this as the view for each item in the adapter.

Comment: @GabeSechan Using a list view sounds perfect. I'd like to use a custom relative layout for each list view item, is that possible?